# How to release the idle connection of c3p0 on my own?

Tags: jdbctemplate, c3p0

I used C3P0 in my program, my datasource will change by user's action. So I want to update the datasource config on my own. The way I'm using is every 10 minutes I will create a new JdbcTemplate with a new C3P0 datasource and abandoned the old one. But I found that as time fly, my machine will keep many connection with mysql.

I've checked the ComboPooledDataSource and JdbcTemplate class, but did not find the way to release the idle connection on my own.
Here is a demo.

```
@Test
    public static void test() {

        try {
            Map<Long, JdbcTemplate> myTemplates = new HashMap<>();

            myTemplates.put(1L, new JdbcTemplate(createPool()));

            final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                try {
                    updatePool(myTemplates);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    // do nothing
                }
            }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void updatePool(Map<Long, JdbcTemplate> myTemplates) throws Exception{
        myTemplates.put(1L, new JdbcTemplate(createPool()));
    }


    private static ComboPooledDataSource createPool() throws Exception {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        dataSource.setUser("xxx");
        dataSource.setPassword("yyy");
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(15);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(10);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(500);
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(60);
        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(10);
        dataSource.setPreferredTestQuery("select 1");
        dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        return dataSource;
    }
```

I hope to find the reason my application create so many connection.
Maybe I should release the idle connection by my own?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you replace the pool, you should call the `close()` method on it first. Something like...

```
private static void updatePool(Map<Long, JdbcTemplate> myTemplates) throws Exception {
  JdbcTemplate old = myTemplates.get(1L);
  if ( old != null ) {
    ((ComboPooledDataSource) old.getDataSource()).close();
  }
  myTemplates.put(1L, new JdbcTemplate(createPool()));
}
```